# How to properly mount a USB flash drive from the console?

Tags: mount, usb-drive

I want to know what are the mount options that I require to mount a USB flash drive.
sudo mount -t auto -L ultra_fit ~/usb_flash -o ?
I mount it and when I try to cd to a folder within the drive, it states "Permission Denied."

To clarify, what are the correct mount options to use when mounting a USB flash drive?

Comment: You can't even create a directory without `sudo` so I don't think you would be able to create the directory in your home drive.  Also you will need `sudo` to mount the drive.  Why don't you talk to your administrator and ask them to help you?  Or why do you not have access to `sudo`?

Comment: I can create directories without using sudo in my home directory. You need to use sudo to create directories outside your home directory, for example under /. Also, I'm a home user, supposedly I'm the administrator of my own computer.

Comment: Anyways, I do have access to sudo.

Answer (score 0):

To make the directory issue:

`mkdir ~/newDirectory`

Then attempt to mount the drive, after mounting the drive you will need to use the `chmod` command to assign the appropriate permissions or `chown` to make yourself the owner, whichever you feel is appropriate.

However you will need `sudo` to do so.

You said you are unable to use `sudo` but then go on to state you are the administrator.  What is the output when you issue `sudo su` and press return and use the password for your user account?

**EDIT**  You added a comment you are able to use `sudo` so does this eliminate your problem?  Are you now able to mount and access the drives as you want?

**EDIT 2**  Try this -

```
mkdir ~/newDirectory
sudo chmod o+rw,g+rw,o+rw ~/newDirectory
sudo mount /dev/sdx ~/newDirectory
```

Then `cd` to your new directory and see if you are able to access the files

Comment: I read somewhere that you can mount a drive (for example, /cdrom) without using sudo. I just wanted to know if I can accomplish the same with my USB flash drive. If not, then that's okay.

Comment: In regards to your method of chmod/chown, is this the same as using "mount -o uid=antman,gid=antman" or are they different? What if I go to another *nix computer, would I have to chmod/chown again to access my USB flash drive?

Comment: No if you set the owner when you mount it you will not have to use chown.  Those parameters you used on mount are specific to that specific action, so even if you took the usb drive out and put it back in to the same computer you would have to run the same command again.  So yes if you take the usb drive out and put it in a different computer you would have to enter that command again.  Now if you make a directory, make yourself the owner and always mount your usb to that directory you will not have to use chown everytime.

Comment: I am not convinced `chown` or `chmod` will work on a filesystem that does not have ownership and permissions in that way (e.g. FAT32) – permissions and the user/group are set in the mount as @manofsteelx says.

Comment: I had no idea this was a FAT32 usb drive.  But that is irrelevant, you are changing the ownership and permissions on the directory on the linux filesystem not on the USB flash drive

Comment: I got confused by @Dylan 's answer. Are you suggesting to use chmod/chown on the mount point, or are you suggesting using chmod/chown on a directory within the mounted drive?

Comment: @Dylan I don't it's necessary to use `sudo` for "Edit 2", line 2 since when you make a new directory in your home directory you are the owner, hence you have already have the "rights" to change the permissions on your own directory. Also I think you meant to write `u+rw,g+rw,o+rw` or `a+rw` (you mentioned the "other" group twice).

Comment: You are right, when you solve the issue let me know what it was